# how to encrypt application.properties in spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

Spring use application.properties as the configure file, and I have created a new app which all working good exception the spring.database.password which does not meet the security requirement in my company. Is there any ways to encryt the psw? is there any example for me?

Comment: if you have the ability to get a key for decryption in whichever way your company's standards allow, you can do this yourself by providing a `PropertySourceFactory` that decrypts your file at startup

Answer (score 2):

You could use [jasypt](http://www.jasypt.org/) to handle the encryption and then use [Jasypt's Spring integration](http://www.jasypt.org/spring31.html) or this [Jasypt Spring Boot Starter](https://github.com/ulisesbocchio/jasypt-spring-boot) to wire it into Spring.